# How to print out errors in the console with the C API for Lua

Tags: c++, c, error-handling, lua, lua-c++-connection

I have been searching high and low for a way to handle errors with the C API for Lua, and simply print them out in the console. Though, I'm unable to find a single working example. What I would like to do is simply something like:

```
static int test(lua_State *L)
{
  if(!lua_isstring(L, 1))
     return luaL_error(L, "This is not a valid string");    
}
```

or

```
static int test(lua_State *L)
{
    try
    {
        if (!lua_isstring(L, 1))
        {
            throw luaL_error(L, "This is not a valid string");
        }
    }
    catch (int e)
    {
        std::cout << "Error " << e << std::endl;
    }
}
```

But nothing works as up to this point. What would be the correct way to do the error handling with the LUA C API and show messages in the console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first code example is one of the correct ways to deal with errors in Lua, but you appear to be confused about how it works.

You are writing a C function that implements an interface that will be exposed to Lua. It works like this Lua code:

```
local function test(s)
    if type(s) ~= "string" then
        error("This is not a valid string")
    end
end
```

The code that made the error in the first place is not the `test` function, it is the code that called it with an invalid argument.

When your Lua code calls that function in an invalid way (for instance `test(42)`), it will raise a Lua error, with the string as the error message. If you call it from a standard Lua interpreter, it will stop the program, print the error message and a stack trace.

If you want to do something else in your Lua code, for instance just print the error message, you can catch the error with `pcall` which works a bit like try / catch in other languages:

```
local ok, err_msg = pcall(test, 42)
if not ok then
    print(err_msg)
end
```

Note that since this error is caused by an invalid argument type, your code can probably be improved by using one of [luaL_checkstring](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#luaL_checkstring) / [luaL_checklstring](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#luaL_checklstring), [luaL_argcheck](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#luaL_argcheck) or [luaL_argerror](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#luaL_argerror) instead of luaL_error directly.

To learn more about how the C API works, I encourage you to read the dedicated section in the book "Programming in Lua (4th edition)".

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same question, and catwell's answer didn't fully answer it for me. What I originally did in my program was simply call

```
luaL_dofile(L, "example.lua");
```

Nothing happened when an error occurred.

*"If you call it from a standard Lua interpreter..."* was a good clue. So I looked at the main in `luac.c` to see what it does:

```
if (lua_pcall(L,2,0,0)!=LUA_OK) fatal(lua_tostring(L,-1));
```

Note that `luaL_dofile` also expands to `lua_pcall`. So, if an error is raised while that file is ... done, the only thing that happens is that the error message is pushed onto `L`'s stack. It is your responsibility to do something with it.

So I modified my code accordingly:

```
#include <stdio.h> // fprintf, stderr
#include <stdlib.h> // exit, EXIT_FAILURE
static void fatal(const char* message) {
  fprintf(stderr,"%s\n", message);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
int main(void) {
  ...
  if (luaL_dofile(L, "example.lua") != LUA_OK) {
    fatal(lua_tostring(L,-1));
  }
  ...
}
```